# Problem importing module using express Not Using Bundler

Tags: node.js, express, axios

Im building a application using express and I dont want to use a bundler. When I import the axios module it gives me the next error: "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "axios". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"."

I also made a repository of the entire project so far here: https://github.com/klaus4323/Natours-Nodejs.git
The code where I want to use axios is in the login.js (I am doing the nodejs online class of Jonas Schemetmann) file:

> import axios from 'axios';
> import { showAlert } from './alerts.js';
>
> export const login = async (email, password) => {
> try {
> const res = await axios({
> method: 'POST',
> url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/users/login',
> data: { email, password },
> });
>
> if (res.data.status === 'success') {
> showAlert('success', 'Logged in succesfully');
> window.setTimeout(() => {
> location.assign('/');
> 5000);
> }
> catch (err) {
> showAlert('error', err.response.data.message);
> }
> };
>
> export const logout = async () => {
> try {
> const res = await axios({
> method: 'GET',
> url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/users/logout',
> });
>
> if ((res.data.status = 'success')) location.reload(true);
> catch (err) {
> showAlert('error', 'Error logging out. Try Again!');
> }
> };

Answer (score 0):

Use like this
import * as axios from 'axios'

Comment: It did not work